# I cannot find compilervars.sh after installing Intel Compiler

Tags: icc, intel-oneapi

I have installed intel compiler on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine through the following link: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/oneapi-standalone-components.html#dpcpp-cpp

I specifically installed Intel® DPC++/C++ Compiler for Linux.

I am trying to run some benchmarks and they require to source the path `<icc_installdir>/bin/compilervars.sh` but I can not find this file.
The installation says that Intel compiler was installed in `/opt/intel/oneapi` but I looked up this directory and there is no bin folder or compilervars.sh. Does anyone know how can I install this file?

Comment: Try with a "find" compilervars.sh : `$ find /opt -name compilervars.sh`

Comment: It appears that setvars.sh replaces compilervars.sh. When I sourced setvars.sh I was able to run icc.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try using the below command to initialize/source the Intel® DPC++/C++ Compiler for Linux?

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/env/vars.sh
```

And also, to confirm whether it is initialized you can check the version of DPCPP compiler by using the below command.

```
dpcpp --version
```

For more information, please find the below link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-programming-guide/top/oneapi-development-environment-setup/use-the-setvars-script-with-linux-or-macos.html